# Silverlight converter in Datagrid

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a radiobutton and textbox in datagird DataGridTemplateColumn.

If radiobutton is cheked,I want to change forecolor of textbox using converter.

I have bound a property to radiobuton and textbox  and I want to change textbox color.

Following is my code:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}"  Foreground="{Binding isTrue, Converter={StaticResource ChangeColor}}" Grid.Column="1" Width="80">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a converter class and convert mehod.Use following code:

```
   SolidColorBrush result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        bool visible = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

        if (visible == true)
        {
            return result = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
        else
            return result;
```

and in Xaml file use like it:

```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Firstname}"  Foreground="{Binding isTrue, Converter={StaticResource ChangeColor}}" Grid.Column="1" Width="80">
```

Comment: Hi, But how can i define converter class in xaml file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in following way.

```
<UserControl.Resources>        
       <Converters:ChangeColor x:Key="ChangeColor"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

You have to put above code in your xaml file.